# DX Auth Configuring

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just got down uploading and configuring what I thought was correctly for the DX Auth plugin for Code Igniter but now I'm getting a "500 Internal Server Error". From that link I'm wanting it to go to the login page but maybe I didn't do something right. http://kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager

Edit:

Okay so what I did was deleted everything from my server and uploaded the application and system folders to my public_html (www) root directory. I created a controller for my CMS that is called kowmanager. What is going to happen when the controller is loaded it will check to see if a session exists and if not then it will load the login model and view and I'm wanting dx auth to handle that but I'm still not sure how to implement it in.

Edit 2: Any ideas?

Comment: Your question needs a lot more information to be answerable. You may have an issue with an `.htaccess` file. Retrace your steps and try to pinpoint which step caused the error.

Comment: Well, now you seem to have a 404 error instead. You still didn't provide anything that would help answer the question. Do you think the issue is with the controller? Post the controller code. Do you think it's related to routing? Post your routes.php. There's practically nothing to work with here.

Comment: Forget about the error now because I did a clean install to start over because of some other issues but now read my first edit. It talks about what I'm trying to do now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is going to happen when the controller is loaded it will check to see if a session exists and if not then it will load the login model and view and I'm wanting dx auth to handle that but I'm still not sure how to implement it in.

If you're using the Session class, the session itself will always exist - what you really want is to check if the user is authorized or not, so just go ahead and load your auth library right away in the controller.

Here's what it might look like:

```
class Kowmanager extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->library('dx_auth');

        // Make sure we don't check permission while on the login page
        $is_login_page = $this->router->method === 'login';

        if ( ! $is_login_page && ! $this->dx_auth->is_logged_in())  
        {  
            redirect('kowmanager/login');
        }
    }

    function login()
    {
        // Make sure the user isn't already logged in
        // Load your login form
        // Process the login
        // Redirect somewhere else once logged in
    }

}
```

It seems that DX Auth is [well documented](http://dexcell.shinsengumiteam.com/dx_auth/), although perhaps a bit [outdated](http://dexcell.shinsengumiteam.com/dx_auth/changelog.html), so just follow some of the [examples](http://dexcell.shinsengumiteam.com/dx_auth/examples/simple.html) they have provided in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you. Some of it was just a little confusing thats all.

Comment: You might want to check out Ion_Auth or even Tank_Auth, I believe they are a bit more recent and maintained. In fact, I think Tank_Auth was based on DX.

Comment: I've seen a lot of stuff like this on cntrollers will an index public function be necessary? public function index()
 {
  $this->load->view('login');
 }

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. `index()` is just the default method called by the controller when there are no URI segments present. It's not actually *required*. Both libraries are easily found by searching the name, here's Tank_auth: http://www.konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/

Comment: Thank you sir. So in other words with having the tank_auth i'm going to download and use I don't need that public function index.

Comment: I think you may be confused about how CI works... In any case, I recommend making a separate controller just for login, password recovery, etc. - anything that doesn't require to be logged in. There are plenty of examples provided - the concept remains the same regardless of which library you choose. Just do your best and don't be afraid to ask another question when you get stuck, after you've done your research.

Comment: One last thing. So with what your saying regardless of which library I choose I'll STILL have to create another controlle for the login, password recovery and what not. I thought that was all handled in one of the two controllers that are in the library package. And besides I have the kowmanager (which is the name of my CMS) so that's the main controller. So when I go to kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager it should see there's no session which means I should be taken to the login but it doesn't all I get is a 404 Not Found error.

Comment: @WesleyMurch let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2440/discussion-between-jeff-davidson-and-wesley-murch)